# Review close vote(s) on question you are currently viewing

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, close-dialog

It would be useful to be able to *easily* *review* the close vote queue for the question you are currently viewing when you see there is a close vote(s) and perhaps you disagree and want to "Leave Open".

[image: Question showing 1 close vote]

In this sense, it would work in a similar way to how you can review suggested edits on the current question, without having to manually navigate to the suggested edits review queue.

You can already do this in a cumbersome, roundabout way, having looked at the close reason then manually navigating to the Close Review queue and using the "filter" option:

[image: Filter Close Review queue]

Whilst "workable", it is relatively slow and slower if there are many close votes for the same tag(s).

Comment: This would also have the advantage that people who came across a question naturally are probably much better suited to judge a post than some random user from the queue.

Comment: The same applies to reopen votes.

Comment: But I mean... isn't this how it already works? If I view a question naturally, I'm already reviewing it, and I'm going to close vote if I think it is off-topic

Comment: @DiminutiveColossus When you "review" the question via the "Close Votes Review queue" you have the option to "Leave Open" - which is not available to you when simply viewing the question "naturally". When you are viewing the question you can simply cast "close votes", you aren't "reviewing close votes" that have already been cast.

Comment: You absolutely have the option to leave open when viewing naturally, don't vote. What you're asking for here is for your natural close votes to count as review tasks, which is a bad idea as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DiminutiveColossus All I'm asking for is a shortcut to the close votes review queue, something which you can already do, just in a more convoluted fashion.

Comment: @DiminutiveColossus 3 Leave Open votes kick a post from the queue, so not voting to close is not at all the same.

Comment: @Zanna so you want to prevent others from reviewing the post?

Comment: @DiminutiveColossus I want to be able to review the post. If I can see it's being wrongly close-voted, then I want to vote to leave it open without fiddling around searching for the review like OP describes. Your accusation is unreasonable. I just want to use the functions of the queue without having to dig for them so annoyingly! If voting Leave Open did nothing, posts with incorrect close votes would stay in the queue until all the votes had aged away or until enough robo-reviewers had voted to close them (don't try to tell me it doesn't happen). PS mods can already do as OP requests.

Comment: @Zanna Review is an abstraction to get people who might not otherwise be looking at a post to look at that post in a targetted manner. When you are already viewing the post you don't need the abstraction in order to view the post, you're already viewing it. That you would like to be able to rob someone else of the chance to review the post is concerning. Do you think that the rest of the community is somehow going to act incorrectly?

Comment: @DiminutiveColossus Is it now? On what experience is your view of this issue based?

Comment: @Zanna many years of reviewing close votes and questions in general on Stack Overflow as well as many years of participation in meta. On what is your's based?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this should be implemented for a couple reasons:

1. You can already see that a question has accrued close votes, *and vote to close it*, from the organic question view page. If you don't think the question is close-worthy, simply don't close it. If everyone follows this procedure, then ideally said question will never need reopen votes in the first place.
2. Questions can have active close votes and *not* be in the review queue; what should users see in that scenario? What if the user has already reviewed the max number of items for the day and tries to use one of their remaining organic close votes? How would "leave open" votes be indicated in the link, or would they?
3. Looking for an item in a closure review queue that you think should remain open, *so that you can vote to leave open*, smacks of canceling votes. While it's true that close votes and reopen votes/leave open votes literally are designed to have opposing purposes/functions, and while the notion of canceling votes expressly *not* being their intended purpose applies specifically to *upvotes/downvotes*, I think we should also consider this warning when using close votes, too. From the way you describe the request, it *sounds* a little like you just want to go through an entire tag and vote to leave questions open wholesale, regardless of their appropriate status. I'm not accusing you of this, but I'm curious why you'd otherwise be asking for this, which leads me to my final reason...
4. And this may be the biggest proverbial nail in the coffin for this request, but is this really a big enough issue to warrant dev time? I obviously don't have numbers to refute such a claim, but from my observation on Stack Overflow, the vast majority of items that are closed are rightfully closed; items that are wrongfully closed tend to get reopened (or posted about on Meta, where Meta then reopens them). Likewise items that get closed temporarily (for lacking an MCVE, lacking clarity, etc.) usually get re-opened after appropriate changes are made. At least on SO, the Reopen Queue's size is peanuts when compared to the Close Vote Queue... it's not like closed questions are struggling to get enough eyes on them in order to get reopened.

Comment: You nailed it ...

Comment: 3 Leave Open votes kick a post from the Close Votes queue, so voting to Leave Open is not the same as *not voting*. Of course Leave Open votes don't *cancel* close votes - those just age away if they aren't retracted and the post isn't closed, regardless of review outcome. Mods have the ability to go to a review from the post, but ordinary users like me have to fiddle around with the review history page, hope it comes up when filtering, etc. So, no need for extra developing, just give everyone with review privilege access to the mod power that allows this.

Comment: @Zanna Actually Leave Open votes *do* work to cancel close votes *in the queue*. If there are competing votes, more are needed before the item can be completed, and like you said, 3 of them will clear the post from the queue. Leave Open votes also don't leave any residual vote on the post; you can't retract a Leave Open vote... once you've reviewed an item, it's reviewed. Also, I think you're drastically underestimating how convoluted the codebase is. However simply you think devs can turn this on, increase the difficulty by a factor or two.

Comment: But they don't cancel the close votes - the close votes stay on the post, even if it is removed from the queue.

Comment: @Zanna Notice I said "in the queue" with emphasis.